# Noise when pedalling uphill?

Tags: noise, flip-flop-hub

I have a bike that recently began riding again after many years.

It is a flip-flop hub. When on the fixie side, there is no noise. When on the freewheel side, there is a grind when riding uphill.

I greased it, but made no difference. What can I do?

Is it better to have the chain tight or slightly loose?

Comment: Clarifications - the fixed wheel side makes no noise when pedalling uphill.  If you flip the wheel over so the chain goes to the freewheel, then you get noise while pedalling or while coasting ? Does the noise get twice as bad if you pedal backwards?  Also, does the chainline change much when comparing the two sides of the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

I get that too. My bike is about three weeks old so it has Nil to do with  bike age. I remedied by using teflon chain wax / lube. May pay to see if it's the pedals or the chain / derailers are all in good nick. Sometimes when a bike has not been ridden for sometime it needs a service or at least a inspection just like a car.